# Meeting Workspace in Outlook 2010

Tags: calendar, outlook, meeting-workspace

I have setup a meeting workspace that I would like my team to use in conjunction with a shared calendar (also in SharePoint). I can link the Calendar into Outlook via the 'Connect to Outlook' button. However, I want to create a meeting and "link" it to the Meeting Workspace, I have found where the Meeting Workspace button is located, but the button is disabled.

I dont know why this is and it is stopping us from getting the full SharePoint meeting experience.

Does anyone know why the button would be disabled? I have found one blog post on it, but the solution is editing registry keys which 'should' not be required... (I would hope).

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Error!!

I figured it out, you need to add something in the Subject and add another recipient to the invitation for it to become enabled...